# how to get the xpath to get all asset param parameter in the below xml

Tags: xml, xpath

```
<DeviceProfile xmlns="http://www.hp.com/schema/m2m/">
    <Metadata>
        <DeviceProfileType>HPIOT</DeviceProfileType>
        <OntologyReference xmlns:tns="http://www.yyy.com/schema/m2m/" xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance" />
            <AssetParams ParamName="Device-ID" DisplayName="Device-ID" Mandatory="true" ReadOnly="true" DataType="String" Category="IoT" LiveUpdate="false" xpath="'Unit-ID''" Decoding="none" MinLength="1" />
            <AssetParams ParamName="deviceHost" DisplayName="Device Host" Mandatory="false" ReadOnly="false" DataType="String" Category="IoT" Decoding="none" />
            <AssetParams ParamName="devicePort" DisplayName="Device Port" Mandatory="false" ReadOnly="false" DataType="number" Category="IoT" Decoding="none" />
            <AssetParams ParamName="deviceMSISDN" DisplayName="Device MSISDN" Mandatory="true" ReadOnly="false" DataType="number" Category="IoT" Decoding="none" />
            <AssetParams ParamName="preferredProtocol" DisplayName="Preferred Protocol" Mandatory="true" ReadOnly="false" DataType="Choice" Category="IoT" Decoding="none" ChoiceElements="TCP,UDP" />
    </Metadata> 
</DeviceProfile>
```

In the above xml code what is an XPath expression to get all the `AssetParam` attributes?

Why isn't `//AssetParams` working?

Comment: //*/AssetParams

Comment: Do you want to get the attributes or the tag itselft.

Comment: i want the assetparams  tag iteslf

Answer (score 1):

Use this (not taking care about *namespaces*) :

```
'//@DisplayName | //@Device-ID | //@Mandatory | //@ReadOnly | //@DataType | //@Category | //@LiveUpdate | //@xpath | //@Decoding | //@MinLength'
```

Comment: To get the attributes of the tag

Answer (score 1):

Your XPath is attempting to select elements that are not bound to any namespace and have the `local-name()` AssetParams.

It is easy to overlook, but all of the elements are bound to a namespace.

On the `DeviceProfile` element:  `xmlns="http://www.hp.com/schema/m2m/"` means that it, and its descendants are bound to that namespace. It would be more apparent if a namespace-prefix were used.

You didn't specify what you were using to execute the XPath, or what version it supports.

An XPath 1.0 expression would be to match any element and then in a predicate, filter by the `local-name()`

```
//*[local-name()='AssetParams']
```

With XPath 2.0 (and higher), you can use a wildcard for the namespace:

```
//*:AssetParams
```

Comment: To get the tag itselft